# htaccess file extension hiding and pass url string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I am trying to hide .php extension and also rewriting the url string with trailing slashes. File extension hiding is working fine but url string is not.

From:

```
http://www.example.com/abc.php?id1=1&id2=2
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/abc/id1/1/id2/2
```

Following is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Multiviews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/([0-9]+)$ $1.php?id=$2&%1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable. Redirect if it satisfies your match conditions.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /abc\.php\?(id1)=(\d+)&(id2)=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /abc/%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]
```

Next, internally rewrite the friendly-url.

```
RewriteRule ^abc/(id1)/(\d+)/(id2)/(\d+)$ /abc.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [NC,L]
```